# How can I get details of all operations being performed by current PowerShell DSC?

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

On a system, a PowerShell DSC is applied, but I do not have the original script that was applied. How can I get a list of all operations that this configuration is supposed to do/ currently doing?

For example, if I have the original script, I can see what programs are being installed and what settings are being applied by the configuration, but how to do it without original script.

I want to uninstall a program being installed by DSC currently, but I am not able to update the DSC to allow removal of the program leaving other parts as is, so removing it seems to be the only option. Before removing it, I want to make sure that it does not do something else important. How can I do that?

Also, if I remove the current DSC, is previous or pending DSC applied?

Comment: `pending.mof` is a configuration that has been sent, but the LCM hasn't applied it yet.  `current.mof` is the configuration in effect.  `previous.mof` is the last successful configuration for rollbacks.  If you remove the current DSC, `pending.mof` will be applied on the next LCM rotation, but `previous.mof` is never applied unless you rollback manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-DscConfiguration` cmdlet.  You can also locate the `.mof` file used to configure `DSC` and examine that located at `C:\Windows\System32\Configuration\`

Comment: Can you give me a little more idea on how to find the mof file and how to open it to get the details?

Comment: @psinaught I've updated his answer with some more detail.  The `Current.mof` should be what you're looking for.  You can view it with any text editor

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I cannot see Current.mof, only Pending. What does that mean? Also, I can only see binary data of Pending.mof using Get-content. Any idea what can I do?

Comment: @psinaught It means your configuration isn't applied.  You should be able to use `Start-DscConfiguration`.  I forgot that MSFT encrypts the mofs by default now.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Is there a way to see what the configuration does before starting it?